# C# looping through a list to find character counts

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm trying to loop through a string to find the character, ASCII value, and the number of times the character occurs. So far, I have found each unique character and ASCII value using foreach statements, and finding if the value was already in the list, then don't add it, otherwise add it. However I'm struggling with the count portion. I was thinking the logic would be "if I am already in the list, don't count me again, however, increment my frequency"
I've tried a few different things, such as trying to find the index of the character it found and adding to that specific index, but i'm lost.

```
    string String = "hello my name is lauren";
        char[] String1 = String.ToCharArray();
       // int [] frequency = new int[String1.Length]; //array of frequency counter
        int length = 0;         
        
        

        List<char> letters = new List<char>();
        List<int> ascii = new List<int>();
        List<int> frequency = new List<int>();


        foreach (int ASCII in String1)
        {
            bool exists = ascii.Contains(ASCII);
            if (exists)
            {
                //add to frequency at same index
                //ascii.Insert(1, ascii);
                //get { ASCII[index]; }
            }
            else
            {
                ascii.Add(ASCII);
                //add to frequency at new index
                
            }
        }


        foreach (char letter in String1)
        {
            bool exists = letters.Contains(letter);
           if (exists)
            {
              //add to frequency at same index

            }
            else
            {
                letters.Add(letter);
                //add to frequency at new index
            }
        }



        
        length = letters.Count;
        for (int j = 0; j<length; ++j)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{letters[j].ToString(),3}  {"(" + ascii[j] + ")"}\t");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is LINQ's `GroupBy` an option?

Comment: anything is an option at this point. I'm so close in my ouput with each character, ASCII value, and frequency. but the frequency is 0 for each because nothing is added to that array

Comment: If you don't mind the performance hit, you could use `string.Replace(charYourLookingFor,Char.MinValue)` and compare their lengths to get the amount of times that character was in the string.

Comment: @DekuDesu What if the char was Char.MinValue?

Comment: If the char `'\0'` needs to be found an alternative could be `string.Replace($"{charYourLookingFor}","")`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but that what you are looking for may be Dictionary<T,T> instead of List<T>. Here are examples of solutions to problems i think you trying to solve.

Counting frequency of characters appearance

```
Dictionary<int, int> frequency = new Dictionary<int, int>();                
            foreach (int j in String)
            {
                if (frequency.ContainsKey(j))
                {
                    frequency[j] += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    frequency.Add(j, 1);
                }
            }
```

Method to link characters to their ASCII

```
Dictionary<char, int> ASCIIofCharacters = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        foreach (char i in String)
        {
            if (ASCIIofCharacters.ContainsKey(i))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                ASCIIofCharacters.Add(i, (int)i);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `TryGetValue` would be better than `ContainsKey`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple LINQ approach is to do this:

```
string String = "hello my name is lauren";

var results =
    String
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Select(x => new { character = x.Key, ascii = (int)x.Key, frequency = x.Count() })
        .ToArray();
```

That gives me:

[image: results]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you want to map each `char` in the provided string to the count of times it appears in the string, right?

If that is the case, there are tons of ways to do that, and you also need to choose in which data structure you want to store the result.

Assuming you want to use linq and store the result in a `Dictionary<char, int>,` you could do something like this:

```
static IDictionary<char, int> getAsciiAndFrequencies(string str) {
  return (
    from c in str
    group c by Convert.ToChar(c)
  ).ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Count());
}
```

And use if like this:

```
var f = getAsciiAndFrequencies("hello my name is lauren");
// result: { h: 1, e: 3, l: 3, o: 1, ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a histogram. But you should not use `List.Contains` as it gets ineffective as the list grows. You have to go through the list one item after another. Better use `Dictionary` which is based on hashing and you go directly to the item. The code may look like this

```
string str = "hello my name is lauren";

var dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
foreach (char c in str)
{
    dict.TryGetValue(c, out int count);
    dict[c] = ++count;
}

foreach (var pair in dict.OrderBy(r => r.Key))
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Value + "x " + pair.Key + " (" + (int)pair.Key + ")");
}
```

which gives

```
4x   (32)
2x a (97)
3x e (101)
1x h (104)
1x i (105)
3x l (108)
2x m (109)
2x n (110)
1x o (111)
1x r (114)
1x s (115)
1x u (117)
1x y (121)
```